# DynamicServerError: Dynamic server usage: request.url in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm Facing an issue while deploying the Nextjs13 App on netlify. The application works fine in the local Environment but while hosting I got an error listed Below

```
{
    "message": "Error: Dynamic server usage: request.url",
    "success": false,
    "status": 500
}
```

app folder directory:-

```
Blog
    [Detail]
      page.jsx
   page.jsx
  Detail
  route.js
```

Code [Detail] page:

```
 export const dynamic = 'auto'
        export const dynamicParams = true
        export const revalidate = false
        export const fetchCache = 'auto'
        export const runtime = 'nodejs'
        export const preferredRegion = 'auto'
        export const maxDuration = 5

        const Detail =  ({ params }) => { 
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [Title, setTitle] = useState(params.Detail);
        const [Loading, setLoading] = useState([]);
        useEffect(() => {
           setLoading(true);
           axios.get(`Detail/?title=${Title}`, {
            cache: "force-cache",
           })
             .then((res) => {
                 setData(res.data);
                 setLoading(false);
                 console.log(res.data, "hello");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("error", error.response.data, error);
            });
        }, [])
        return(<></>)
        }
```

the console shows me the error "message": "Error: Dynamic server usage: request.url",

I have tried the dynamic  but i have no idea how to use this and where and getting the same error every time